# Where to place maven

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle

[Here I am attaching image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxowW.png)

I'm trying to place maven here but It's not adding here giving me some error.
here I'm attaching the second image , with Exact Error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LeoVW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Android Studio Arctic Fox, it has changed to `settings.gradle` file:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check the project level Gradle file and change accordingly.

```
 buildscript {
    
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.2'
        }
    }
    
    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
            maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        }
    }
    
    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

I hope it's helpful to you!

Comment: Since Android Studio Arctic Fox, is has changed to settings.gradle file's location has been changed ,where we should implement our mavens and etc.

Answer (score 0):

Go to build.gradle(project) and add

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { 
            url "https://jitpack.io"; 
        } 
    }
}
```

References:

- [build.gradle(Module)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLE36.jpg)
- [build.gradle(project)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLE36.jpg)